# toString function or (std::string) cast overload in c++

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, c++14

I am writing a class which I want to be converted into a string.

Should I do it like this:

```
std::string toString() const;
```

Or like this:

```
operator std::string() const;
```

What way is more accepted?

Comment: Are you using C++11? If so, you can use an explicit cast operator. Otherwise, you should definitely prefer the former (on C++98 or C++03).

Comment: @CodyGray I corrected my tags

Comment: I would also consider a free function `std::string to_string(const Type&)` just because there is `std::to_string` for integral and arithmetic data types. And keep it in the same namespace as your class.

Comment: Note that `operator std::string() const;` is a **conversion** operator; it can be used when the source code contains a cast, but it can also be used without a cast. That is, it **not** a **cast overload**.

Comment: One factor I'd take into account is whether you can create a textual representation using only the public interface of the class or whether you require access to private (or protected) members.  If it can be done with nothing more than the public interface, I'd prefer a non-member function to avoid violating the single-responsibility principle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The classes that have a "string" representation in the standard library (like std::stringstream, for example) use `.str()` as a member function to return a text. If you want to be able to use your class into generic code as well, better to use the same convention (`toString` is "*Javanese*" and `ToString` "*Sharpish*").

About the use of a conversion operator, that makes sense only if your class is specifically designed to interwork with strings in string expressions (converting to a string is in fact a "promotion", like a `int` becoming `long` implicitly).

If your class "demotes" into a string (loses information in doing so), better to have the cast operator explicit (`explicit operator std::string() const`).

If it is unrelated with string semantics, and just has to be occasionally converted, consider explicitly named functions.

Note that, if `a` is a variable, the semantics you have to think about its usage are:

```
a.str();       // invoking a member function 
               // mimics std::stringstream, and std::match_results 

to_string(a);  // by means of a free function 
               // mimics number-to-text conversions 

std::string(a) // by means of an explicit cast operator 
               // mimics std::string construction
```

If your class has nothing to do with strings, but only has to participate in I/O, then consider the idea not to convert to string, but to write to a stream, by means of a...

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const yourclass& yourclass)
```

so that you can do...

```
std::cout << a;

std::stringstream ss;
ss << a;   // this makes a-to-text, even respecting locale informations.
```

...maybe even without the need to allocate any string-related memory.

Comment: "`toString` is "*Javanese*" or "*Sharpish*"" -- Only "Javanese". C# (actually .NET) uses `ToString`.

Comment: @hvd: tank you. Fixed.